# Rails 5 - implement reusable comment model - views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

In my app that I am building to learn RoR, I have a similar situation like this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5138065/rails-implementing-a-reuseable-comment-model). Now my question is how to change my views for this?

I have an Annotation model, a Document model and a Comment model. If I switch to a polymorphic association such that my Annotations and my Documents can have Comments, how to do the view (in the partial)?

This is the current partial:

```
<%= simple_form_for([@annotation, @annotation.comments.build], html: { class: 'form-vertical', multipart: true }) do |f| %>

   <%= f.error_notification %>

   <%= f.input :commenter, :as => :hidden, :input_html => { :value => current_user.username }, label: false %>

   <%= f.input :body, placeholder: 'comment', focus: true, label: false %>

   <%= f.button :submit, 'Save' %>

<% end -%>
```

### Update

Did further research and have changed as follows in my annotation view: `<%= render 'comments/form', :object => @annotation%>`

and as follows in my documents view: `<%= render 'comments/form, :object => @document %>`

And adjusted this in my partial:

```
<%= simple_form_for([object, object.comments.build], html: { class: 'form-vertical', multipart: true }) do |f| %>
```

Now, when adding a comment to a document, I get an error in my CommentsController - logical that is :-) .

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in CommentsController#create

This is my current CommentsController:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @annotation = Annotation.find(params[:annotation_id])
    @comment = @annotation.comments.create(comment_params)
    redirect_to annotation_path(@annotation)
  end

  def destroy
    @annotation = Annotation.find(params[:annotation_id])
    @comment = @annotation.comments.find(params[:id])
    @comment.destroy
    redirect_to annotation_path(@annotation)
  end

  private
    def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:commenter, :body)
  end
end
```

How (best) to change this ?

### Update

I now have implemented the same for another object/model/class called "tag" using `:as => :tagable` and I can create, list, etc for the Annotation, yet I cannot delete.

The listing (as a partial) is called with:

```
<%= render 'tags/tag_list', :object => @annotation %>
```

or:

```
<%= render 'tags/tag_list', :object => @document %>
```

When opening the Annotation / Document record, it throws the error:

> undefined method `object' for #
>   Did you mean?  object_id

... on this line:

```
<td><%= link_to '', [tag.object, tag], method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Please confirm deletion!' }, :class => "glyphicon glyphicon-remove" %></td>
```

What should I change ??

### SOLUTION FOUND

change line to

```
<td><%= link_to '', [object, tag], method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Please confirm deletion!' }, :class => "glyphicon glyphicon-remove" %></td>
```

Comment: What issues do you have with the partial above? On the surface it looks ok to me but I may be missing something.

Comment: this one works for the object/class "Annotation". Not with the object "Document" - and I would want one for both if at all possible.

Comment: Document is the same format as Annotation right? So just replace `annotation` with `documentation` above and it should work.

Comment: Agree; yet then I have 2+ forms. Is it possible to create just one that I use in all cases.

Comment: You could just re-use the form and pass in the object (i.e. `@annotation` or `@documentation`). I can answer that question, it's very straightforward.

Comment: Please do then I will upvote and accept; it is my first case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to fetch correct commentable somehow. The simplest solution would be like this:

```
def create
  commentable = detect_commentable
  commentable.comments.create(comment_params)
  redirect_to commentable_path(commentable)
end

private

def commentable_path(commentable)
  case commentable
  when Document
    document_path(commentable)
  when Annotation
    annotation_path(commentable)
  else
    fail 'unknown commentable'
  end
end

def detect_commentable
  if params[:annotation_id]
    Annotation.find(params[:annotation_id])
  elsif params[:document_id]
    Document.find(params[:document_id])
  else
    fail 'Commentable not found'
  end
end
```

It is not the best code, obviously (because of maintenance requirements, for one thing). But this should get you started.

Comment: not sure I understand the "commentable" bit. Does that assume I have changed my belongs_to (etc) to :commentable, :polymorphic => true ? Correctly understood it goes into my CommentsController?

Comment: @DimitrideRuiter: yep, that's comments controller. And don't you have polymorphic association already?

Comment: @DimitrideRuiter: yes, of course. How else are you going to refer to things that you comment on?

Comment: excuse my ignorance ls - have added the polymorphic etc. yet get error now unknown attribute 'commentable_id' for Comment. Looks like I still need to add some reference - but which one then?

This would then be the migration: rails g migration AddCommentableToComments commentable:reference 
correct?

Comment: @DimitrideRuiter: have you checked the rails guide? http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations

Comment: Yes, I have - tx. And followed it. When saving the comment, now get next error: undefined local variable or method `detect_commentable' for #<CommentsController:0x007fcdcf6ebb18> on this line... commentable = detect_commentable

Comment: changed def commentable into def detect_commentable. Now, creation works. Listing of comments works to after simple change. Up next is deletion/destroy - tx for the help so far, Sergio!

Comment: @DimitrideRuiter: yay! :)

Comment: Now understand basic of how this works. Going to reapply to another case to learn better. Meanwhile, could you help with this one ??http://stackoverflow.com/q/39484844/4201809

Comment: see my update. Tried to replicate, while I made good progress, yet get stuck a bit.

Comment: I believe you mean `def commentable` to be `def detect_commentable`?

Comment: @SanderGarretsen: indeed. Thanks for the catch.

Comment: @DimitrideRuiter: you can't add on to questions like that. This answer solves your original problem. What happens next (when you add more functionality), is out of scope here.

Comment: @SanderGarretsen - indeed that was the change I made yesterday too

Comment: @SergioTulentsev - am learning :-) thanks for pointing it out. Appreciated.