# Rails 5 - model with 2 fields referring to same object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

In the app I am building to learn RoR, I have a model "Document" and a model "Business Partner". On the "Document" model, I have 2 fields ("Sender" and "Receiver") referring to the model "Business Partner".

How do I model twice a belongs_to the same target with different fields? What should the migration be?

Related question: how do I model the relationship to it self for business partner? i.e. one company has many business partners, yet can be a business partner too. Note - not to the same record (company A cannot have a relationship to company A (itself).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you've got columns `sender_id` and `receiver_id` for the sender and receiver relationships on your `Document` model (i.e. on your `documents` table), you can do something like this:

```
class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sender, class_name: "BusinessPartner"
  belongs_to :receiver, class_name: "BusinessPartner"
end
```

There's no particular migration for this as long as you've got those columns there on the table (if you've named them something else, just replace `sender` and `receiver` above by whatever column name minus the `_id` part).

And then for your `BusinessPartner` model:

```
class BusinessPartner < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sent_documents, class_name: "Document", foreign_key: "sender_id"
  has_many :received_documents, class_name: "Document", foreign_key: "receiver_id"
end
```

Here, `sent_documents` will fetch all rows in the `documents` table where `sender_id` matches the id of the `BusinessPartner`, and similar for `received_documents`.

More info in the [Rails docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#options-for-belongs-to-foreign-key).

Regarding your second question, there is a [section of the Rails docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#self-joins) describing this, it is called "Self Joins". However, given that you want to model a many-to-many relationship, you will need a slightly special table arrangement. See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19770888/rails-self-join-scheme-with-has-and-belongs-to-many/19773229) for some details on how to setup that arrangement. That is actually a somewhat tricky topic in itself, if you're interested in details I'd recommend asking a separate question on it (although that SO post answers it pretty well).

Comment: tx Chris; didn't know it was called self join. Will work on this one. Can you help me with this post (http://stackoverflow.com/q/39829023/4201809) too perhaps?

Comment: Well, I'd like to settle this question first. Did this answer work for you?

Comment: Likely yes - main thing for me to figure out is the self join adding attributes to the relationship - think I will need a separate table for it. Due for tomorrow.

Comment: is working so far; can create, update... yet, for some reason get a no method error on my business partner index page: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass on this line: '<% @business_partners.each do |business_partner| %>'

Comment: found the error - in the controller for index method - was singular.

Comment: Chris - in my business partner index view I want to include the number of documents send and received. How would I do that in this case? sender.documents logically does not work there

Comment: `business_partner.sender_documents.count` and `business_partner.receiver_documents.count` should work.

Comment: Come to think of it, those should be renamed `sent_documents` and `received_documents`, I'll update my answer above.

Comment: works well! Ready to help me with the other question ;-) ?